# Low FPS on League Of Legends ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

I have been having real bad FPS on league of legends right after I downloaded league on Ubuntu,   I only get 40-55 FPS on very high settings

I have league of legends through play on Linux,

**my specs are:**
*Ubuntu14.04LTS/Intel Core i7 4700MQ 2.4-4.8GHz/Nvidia Geforce GTX 765M 2GB/8GB 1600MHz DDR3/1920x1080x60/1TB 7200RPM HDD*

**on windows 8.1 i get 180+ FPS with it maxed out even with shades maxed.**

I am using: Nvidia binary driver-version 331.113 from Nvidia 331 (Proprietary,tested)

*I am hoping to use League of legends on Ubuntu indefinitely, I'm starting to make the purge of Windows from my machines.    the only thing holding me back is my favourite game League of legends.*

**if you good people of the Ubuntu community can help me fix this problem, I can once and for all, UN-install windows 8.1 and all other windows versions from all my pc's.**

*in my case at least, gaming is the only reason I haven’t made the conversion to Linux.*

**does anyone know how I can fix this? I appreciate the help!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

> I only get 40-55 FPS on very high settings

So turn the settings down.

You're doing this through Wine. League of Legends is uses Direct3D. Microsoft has not made DirectX available natively for Linux so Wine has to translate all those Direct3D calls into OpenGL... And that takes time.

One thing that might be an idea is switching to a [CSMT-patched build of Wine](https://launchpad.net/~foresto/+archive/ubuntu/winepatched?field.series_filter=trusty). These essentially have multi-threading for the translation process, and that speeds things up quite a bit in *some* (not all) games. Until they're pulled into the main version of Wine, the patches can run behind the standard builds but it's largely worth it.

Comment: so is what your saying there is nothing i can do... wine just makes it slower.... i want to keep my high settings, but thanks for the tip, i bought an i7 haswel for this reason. now hoe would i go about CSMT-patched build of wine? and what is CSMT

Comment: CSMT is the Direct3D [command stream multithreading](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2013-September/101106.html) implementation by wine developer Stefan Dösinger. It significantly improves performance of some games.

It's not part of the official wine releases yet, but if you're willing and able to follow directions and do a little configuration, you can use it now via the packages in my PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~foresto/+archive/ubuntu/winepatched

I made fresh builds this week for Trusty, Utopic, and Vivid (all the currently supported Ubuntu releases except 12.04).