# Ubuntu 15.10 - League of Legends - Nvidia GTX 960 - 15 FPS

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games, playonlinux

I'm using a Nvidea GTX 960 on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine.
I've gotten everything setup and working well on my machine after a few days of tinkering and I love it. The only downfall is that when I use PlayonLinux to play League of Legends in wine, I'm only getting ~15 FPS after minions spawn.

At first I thought I needed to mess with my game settings (all now low) or mess with my drivers (have latest) but after two days of trial and error I've seen no improvement. 
I've also set the CPU process for the game to high, and tried borderless/fullscreen.

Hoping to identify my problem or bottleneck so I could solve, I thought this card would be powerful enough to handle the game, but old enough to have good support. 
When viewing my system monitor my processor never gets above 50% so I don't think thats the issue.
However, my GPU is spiking around 80-90% so I'm assuming my issue is here.

I understand why this is stressful on the card with the Wine emulation , but I'm at a loss now as to what to do to fix the issue when I see other posts with users with older cards can get [playable performance around 50FPS.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560542/low-fps-on-league-of-legends-ubuntu-14-04) 
Was trying to look into 'overclocking' it, but was more interested in buying a second card, or a more powerful card.

I have no idea what my next step would be to troubleshoot or solve or purchase a second card / new card or where to start to overclock my existing card and am looking for any guidance.

After trying everything I could find regarding editing game files or tweaks Ive realized messing with the game isn't going to get me up to 60 or 100 FPS so I needed to stray away from the game specific optimization threads and have been focusing on the best route to increase my overall performance.

Though I have no idea whhere to turn to tweak, optimize, buy, or install now.

Please help

------------additional specs----------------

**Processor:** AMD Phenon II x6 1090T

**GPU:** GeForce GTX 960 4GB

**RAM:** 24 GB

**Monitors:** 1x dispay port, 1x dvi to vga for tv/second monitor

**HD:** SSD 150GB
video
**Driver:**
I've tried the latest NVIDIA binary driver - version 391.28 (nvidia-361)(open source) and the last proprietary driver (nvidia-352-updates) to no effect.

*Please let me know what other info I can provide.
Thank you for your time*

*Side story - I asked my most computer savy friend for help and he said 'if you cant get your graphics to work yourself you are in over your head and should just go back to windows', though I am determined to do what it takes and appreciate any guidance or direction yall may provide.*

Answer (score 2):

Mock-answer: DOTA2 works natively ;)

More serious answer: Have you checked out other folks' suggestions at https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10436 ? Some people appear to be reporting fairly good success with minimal work, although "compile Wine with these patches" may be outside of your personal definition of minimal!

I've noticed in a quick perusal (for example http://metaphysical.zz.mu/league-of-legends/lol-on-linux-the-three-ways/) that there's often mention of running it via OpenGL being more reliable but slower, so you could always try the *opposite* of what's generally suggested and change the game config file to use

```
x3d_platform=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, though all my IRL friends play league so thats a big factor in the gaming decision ;].  I've seen notes about patching wine so I'll try that this week. Its starting to look like I may have just gotten a video card that doesnt work well with league on linux at this time and i should buy a different card. (My fault for not doing enough research.) - I'll try your gamefile edit suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

i installed it here.
May i help you ?
Please, witch resulution and graphic options do youset to the game ?

Can you open a Dota2 to do a comparison with benchmark ? To do it together ?! You don't need to play at 60 fps

Remember you are playing on wine, soo you will lost some 20 fps at 30  and more fps...

The phenon II x6 1090T has less perfomance than a corei5 from an intel that is a minimum recomended for a gamer.

Soo, i recomended you to use a 1280x720  resolution and use all graphic options on low.
For you that need more perfomance you need to pay attention to minimal recomended features.
Remember you are using wine
https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Phenom+II+X6+1090T